# Text from textarea saved to mysql to php overflows inside div

Tags: php, mysql, css, html, textarea

i have a problem in my blog proj, i have a textarea that the user can type and im passing it to my mysql table, the problem is that the text overflows on my `<li>` ive tried wordwrap() but still other text keeps overflowing i dont how to "format" it so that automatically itll be formated to fit on my div's or my way of doing this is wrong o.O?, imma newbie on php obviously :P..

thanks...

```
<?php 
session_start();
function __autoload($className)
    {
        require $className . '.php';

    }
    $emptyMsg ='';
    $conn=new connection();
    $conn->conn('localhost','****','');

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    die('Log In 1st!<a href="loginpage.php">Log In</a>');
}

$query = "SELECT blog_content FROM tbl_blog";
$queryResult=mysql_query($query) or die();

?>

<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
p
{
}
#nav
{

}
ul li
{
    list-style:none;
}
#blog_wrap
{
    clear:both;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:blue;
}

.content 
{   
    width:700px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:gray;  
    color:lightgreen;
    text-align:left;
    margin:10px 0 0 50px;
}
.content ul li
{
    color:red;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:visible;
    }

.content2
{   
    width:700px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
    color:lightgreen;
    margin:10px 0 0 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav" >
    <ul >
    <li>Welcome!!!<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></li>
    <li><a href="">Edit Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="createBlog.php">Create Blog</a></li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Sign Out</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div id="blog_wrap">

<?php
$count=0;
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($queryResult))
    {   
        if($count % 2 ==0) 
            {   
                echo '<div class="content">';
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . $rows['blog_content'] . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            else
            {   
                echo '<div class="content2">';
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . $rows['blog_content'] . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            $count++;
    }

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a change to your CSS class .content.  It should read:

```
.content {   
  width:700px;
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  background-color:gray;  
  color:lightgreen;
  text-align:left;
  margin:10px 0 0 50px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Adding "overflow:hidden" to a fixed width container prevents the content from flowing out.

Comment: Please also note that overflow:hidden will prevent scrollbars if overflowing occurs.

Comment: what happen with overflow:hidden is it cuts the text it doesn't go to a new line the other text beyond my li dissapears